# How to find a potential function for conservation field vector field $F$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$F=\left(y\cos \left(xy\right)+e^{x+y}\right)i+\left(x\cos \left(xy\right)+e^{x+y}\right)j$$

also show that $$∫_cF ⋅ dr = e^2-e^{-2}$$
where c is the straight line from $\left(-1,-1\right)$ to $\left(1,1\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the potential is a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\nabla f = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}= \vec{F}
$$

Can you solve this equation ?

Once you have found $f(x,y)$, the fundamental theorem of line integrals states that
$$
\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = f(1,1)-f(-1,-1)
$$

Comment: $(-y^2sin(xy)+e^{x+y}) , (-x^2sin(xy)+e^{x+y}),$

Comment: I am not sure what this expression is, remember $f$ is a scalar function, so it only has one component. You need to solve the equation $\nabla f=\vec{F}$:

$$f(x,y)=\int y\cos xy+e^{x+y}\; dx +g(y)=\sin xy +e^{x+y}+g(y)$$

Knowing  that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x \cos x y+e^{x+y}$, can you find the expression of $g(y)$ (which will give you $f(x,y)$ explicitly) ?

Comment: You should find $f(x,y)=\sin xy + e^{x+y}+K$, where $K$ is an arbitrary constant in $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, with this potential, you obtain $f(1,1)-f(-1,-1)=e^{2}-e^{-2}$ as the other terms cancel one another.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow, Can you show me step by step if possible. Thanks

Comment: Your starting point is $$\pmatrix{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}= \vec{F} = \pmatrix {F_x \\ F_y}$$

So you can start by solving 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = F_x = y \cos xy + e^{x+y}
$$

Integrating with respect to $x$ yields 
$$
f(x,y)=\sin xy+e^{x+y} +g(y)
$$

Can you pursue?

Comment: After that differentiate with respect to y $$f_y = cos(xy)+e^{x+y} + g_y$$, now compare $f_y$ will give you $g_y=0$

Comment: That is correct, You got it!

Comment: Whats after that?

Comment: So now you have found your potential $f(x,y)$. See my answer for the rest: in essence, use the theorem that tells you that your integral equals the difference of this potential between both endpoints of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the potential function of a conservative force, you choose some point, lets say (-1,-1), than take the line integral of the force from (-1,-1) to (x,y),  which will give you the potential function of the force.

$$\int_{(-1,-1)}^{(x,y)} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r} = U(x,y)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy when you know differential forms.

Let $∫_{C} F⋅ dr = ∫_{C} \,\left(y\cdot\cos \left(xy\right) + \exp \left(x+y\right)\right)dx + \left(x\cdot\cos \left(xy\right) + \exp \left(x+y\right)\right)dy, $

where $ω = \left(y\cdot\cos \left(xy\right) + \exp \left(x+y\right)\right)dx + \left(x\cdot\cos \left(xy\right) + \exp \left(x+y\right)\right)dy$ is your differential form.

I assume that you consider the vector field over $\mathbb{R^2}$. This vector space is simply connected and thus star-shaped. Therefore you can apply; sorry I wasn't of help. Poincaré's Lemma. This basically tells you that every closed differential form is also exact. In the title of your question you are looking for a potential function. Therefore I can assume (without calculation) that the differential form above is closed. Since it is exact it does not matter which curve C you use to integrate over! Only the end points matter. Hence take the curve $\phi: \left[-1;1\right] → \mathbb{R}, x → \left(x,x\right)$.

The theory of differential forms now says that

$$∫_{C} F ⋅ dr = ∫_{-1}^{1} \langleω\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right), \phi'\left(x\right)\rangle dx$$.

Since $\phi'\left(x\right) = \left(1,1\right)$ and $ω\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right) = 2\left(x\cdot\cos \left(x^2\right) + \exp \left(2x\right)\right)$, it follows that

$∫_{C} F⋅ dr = ∫_{-1}^{1} 2\left(x\cdot\cos \left(x^2\right) + \exp \left(2x\right)\right) = \exp \left(2\right) - \exp \left(-2\right)$.

Comment: Please do delete those horrible * between symbols. If you simply write $\;2x\;$ instead of $\;2*x\;$ everybody will understand that's multiplication, and even if you want to be extremely clear you can use $\;\cdot\;$ to denote multiplication...